# Testing multi collinearity of ordinal variables in R

Tags: r, regression, multicollinearity, ordinal-data

I want to test if there is multi collinearity in my dataset. This is made up of multiple ordinal independent variables. Am I correct that this should be done as shown below

```
Model <- lm(BinaryVar~ OrdV1+OrdV2+OrdV3+OrdV4)

Library(car)
Vif(Model)
```

This yields GVIF values and GVIF^1/(2*Df) which I believe are equivalent to VIF.

Is this the correct way to treat ordinal variables and calculate multicollinearity?

I have read that you should turn ordinal variables into dummy variables to do this here [Testing multi-collinearity of ordinal independent variables in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/477444/testing-multi-collinearity-of-ordinal-independent-variables-in-r)

I have found nothing else to confirm this. Is my method of calculating VIF correct?